# How to find Exosuit upgrade locations (drop pods)

Tags: no-mans-sky

I'm getting tired of having a small amount of inventory spaces. I know you can use signal boosters to find locations of drop pods on a planet.

<s>I know that once you get the Atlas pass v1 each space station has an upgrade, but I don't want to just keep flying to different star systems to get upgrades.</s>  I know that each space station has an exosuit upgrade that you can buy with units, but I don't want to keep warping to new solar systems.

Which option should I use to find drop pods, if possible, from signal boosters? Is/are there other ways to find drop pods on planets also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To upgrade your Exosuit, you have one of three options to choose from:

**Signal Booster**
In order to locate drop pods, you need to build a [Signal Booster](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Signal_Booster). To build this, simply up on D-Pad for PS4 and X1 or <kbd>Z</kbd> for PC and scroll through the list until it appears. Once you have built the Signal Booster, interacting with it will prompt you to insert a [drop pod coordinate data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MNhd.png). After the chip has been inserted, the option to scan for a [drop pod](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Drop_Pod)<sup>1|2</sup> will appear.

**Exocraft**
You also have the option to search for drop pods using an [Exocraft](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Exocraft) with the [Signal Booster Upgrade Sigma](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Exocraft) tech installed. If you have this tech installed, simply press the scan button or open up the [quick menu](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Quick_Menu) to scan for drop pods. It is likely you will also need the drop pod coordinate data, but at the time of writing, I am not 100% sure

**Space Station**
While your question indicates you would rather not continue to warp between systems, this option is still available to purchase for units if you do not have the proper resources to scavenge the planets. However, if you do choose this route, be sure to avoid [uncharted star system](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Star_system#Other_classifications). These systems lack space stations and you will not be able to acquire the Exosuit upgrade.

After your hunting is complete and you have located the Exosuit upgrade (either on the plant, moon, or spacespace) it will provide of one three different types of inventory upgrades

1. **General**, which is standard inventory space
2. **Cargo**, which is a separate inventory space dedicated to stacking products
3. **Tech**, which is a separate inventory space decided to installing technology.

---

**Additional Sources** (provided by [chat discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80995/discussion-between-wondercricket-and-timmy-jim))

- [GameFaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/739857-no-mans-sky/76853438)<sup>1</sup>
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/921w6o/where_to_find_drop_pod_coordinate_data/)<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 6):

I actually did this a much quicker way than visiting "Shelters". I actually just flew over the planets surface and searched for the drop pods myself, because it was much more quicker and efficient for me than having to visit shelters the whole time.

Comment: It really depends on the planet if this will be faster or not. One day I flew for a good 30 minutes and found no drop found whereas the next day I found a cluster of drop pods in a close proximity.

Comment: I think it is more the exact location on a planet which increases the amount of drop pods. I upgraded my exo suit all on one planet to the max and sometimes I found a bunch of pods at one place and sometimes I was flying for like 20 minutes w/o. Also I noticed that larger buildings tend to appear in packs. If there is one large building there is a good chance there are more buildings close by. Yesterday I found 3 trading outposts next to each other. So I guess this is the procedural algorithm that generates those sites on a wider scale.

Comment: This works really well at night or on otherwise dark planets, because the pods have a distinctive glowing outline to them.